# Expose public ports only to the sshed user

Tags: ssh, iptables, firewalld, remote-management

We have a VPS running on AWS, although generic solution is expected regardless of hosting vendor.

This VPS is acting as a Jump Box (running CentOS 6) for various other internal server such as SSH access to various other boxes (which are connected to the Jump Box thru reverse SSH). The Jump Box exposes random higher port for each service.

Is there a possibility to expose these higher ports only to the IP address which is currently SSH'ed into the Jump Box?

I was thinking about scanning output of `who -a` to filter the IP address and update the `IPTABLES` using a cronjob or maybe update the security group of AWS using API. But this approach seems sketchy. Any suggestions?

Comment: Something along the lines of `portmap -l`  ... [man portmap](https://linux.die.net/man/8/portmap)

Comment: @RubberStamp Interesting! Checking...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is this necessary or desirable? What benefit does this provide? What security risk does it address?

Comment: Combining the IP identification from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/996286/3485669) with the ability to run a script upon ssh connection recommended [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/397696) it seems you could set up your IPTABLES upon connection .. provided you know the ports on the JumpBox you want to allow connection to...

Comment: @igal The idea is to have a robust security auth. We do not have control over the authentication of the servers behind the jumpbox, some of them have ssh with password auth, and web based login with no strong password policy. So the jumpbox with ssh cert login provides a stronger security and in case a user is to be removed, just removing the user from jumpbox removes complete access. (Unless someone managed to have a backdoor in the servers behind the jumpbox, trying to address that problem by having somekind of logging).

Comment: @Forty3 I have been thinking to install knockd, but rather using port knocking, have a script running on the jumpbox that will scan the logged in user ip's using who -i and push them in the knock log and open up the ports... the idea remains the same as yours, but configuration becomes easier.

Comment: @user1263746 It sounds like you're describing the point of having the jumpbox. That makes sense to me. But that's not what your question is asking about. What's the point of only making ports on the jumpbox only accessible to "the currently logged in user"?

Comment: @igal Jump Box is exposing the ports of reverse sshed boxes to public. jumpboxip:<reverseportofinternalservers>. The internal servers are not hardened. You have a point that jumpbox should not expose the ports to public and one should log into jumpbox and then setup the access, but this is one of the requirements. Hence the idea of sshed users having access to the port provides an easier way to open ports from the outside and cant be accidentally kept open.

Comment: @user1263746 Oh. I think I may have misunderstood the question. You want to only open the ports for *specific* users, is that right? I thought you only wanted them to be open to one user at a time (i.e. the currently logged in user). If that's the case then I think the question could be stated more clearly.

Comment: @igal Specific IP address, So that a remote location having a Dynamic IP, but a gateway running OpenWRT autossh'ed into the jumpbox will allow it's user to access the servers. Simultaneously a user sitting in a coffee shop who is ssh'ed into the jump server will also have the access. The limitations are explained by sebasth below. Your guidance in formatting or question correction will always help! Thanks!

Comment: @user1263746 Ok. Well, I think that this question is stated very unclearly. Consider the expression: "the IP address which is currently SSH'ed into the Jump Box". What does this mean? Is only one user able to log in to jump box at one time? Wouldn't there potentially be multiple IP addresses logged in simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build the described system using *iptables*, *ipset* and *pam_exec*.

The idea is following: There is a separate chain containing rules to allow incoming traffic to these higher ports. Iptables INPUT chain contains an *ipset* rule matching your logged in hosts, jumping to the separate chain. 
On successful log in, a pam_exec runs a script (at PAM session open) adding the remote host's IP address to the ipset set, and similarly removes it when PAM session is closed.

### Configuring IPTABLES and IPSET

Create a set for user's IP addresses. Since ipsets are not persistent, so you need to configure the set to be created on boot before iptables are restored.

```
ipset -N users hash:ip
```

Configure iptables. A new `INPUT-users` chain which will contain the rules to allow traffic for logged in users.

```
iptables -N INPUT-users
```

If the source address is in `users` set, jump to `INPUT-users` chain.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set users src -j INPUT-users
```

Add relevant rules to `INPUT-users` chain. These rules will be used for traffic with source address matching your user's. For example to allow `tcp` port `16384`:

```
iptables -A INPUT-users -p tcp --dport 16384
```

### Configuring PAM

Create following scripts to be executed on pam session open/close. The IP address will be in `PAM_RHOST` environmental variable set by [`pam_exec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man8/pam_exec.8.html).

`/etc/security/pam_exec-session_open`:

```
#!/bin/sh
ipset --exist --add users "$PAM_RHOST"
```

`/etc/security/pam_exec-session_close`:

```
#!/bin/sh
ipset --del users "$PAM_RHOST"
```

Then configure pam to use them for ssh sessions. Append to `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
session optional    pam_exec.so type=open_session /etc/security/pam_exec-session_open
session optional    pam_exec.so type=close_session /etc/security/pam_exec-session_close
```

### Pitfalls

- If your user has multiple ssh sessions open, closing any of them will remove the IP address from the ipset. To avoid this, you need to write some check for the session_close script to remove the IP address only if it is the last session remaining for the user.
- Should your user connect behind NAT, after connecting anyone behind the same NAT will match the ipset rule (allowed access).

Comment: This is near perfect!

Answer (score 6):

### If you know your destination/port as you're initiating ssh connection

I would suggest, ideally, that you connect to JumpBox with something like `ssh -L 8080:10.0.0.1:80 <JumpBox address>` where you're seeking *10.0.0.1* **which is behind firewall/NAT but is accessible to JumpBox**.

This creates a connection and binds to 127.0.0.1 (localhost) such that if you open a browser (*or some other software*) on your client and connect to *http://localhost:8080* your packets will be routed to *10.0.0.1:80* as if you were accessing right from your JumpBox itself.

---

### If port numbers/destinations cannot be known at [ssh] connection time

With the caveat that the client be configured to use a SOCKS/SOCKS5 proxy, you could provide access for connected clients to any resource accessible to the server:

Connect to your VPS using “Dynamic Forwarding”

1. `ssh -D 1080 <JumpBox address>`
2. Configure client's software to use SOCKS proxy server `localhost:1080`
3. Connections via configured software will be tunneled such that it's like you're connecting to whatever destination from the JumpBox itself.